# Redux form is not initialized correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

i have component containing fields and i'm using redux form.
I use initial values prop in my container like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const quantity = formsState(state).getIn([
    'orderEntry', 'values', 'quantity']);
  const price = formsState(state).getIn([
    'orderEntry', 'values', 'price']);
  return {
    initialValues: fromJS({
      quantity: ownProps.quantity,
      price: ownProps.price,
    }),
  };
};
```

Then i use a refresh button through which i dispatch an action so as my price should be updated. The refresh button re-run this component. But checking up the state i see that the price is not set to the initial price i assign. Why the initialValues is not executing?

Answer (score 1):

I add enable Reinitialize: true to my redux-form declarion. This solve my issue